# Compilation error when using Generics C# 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, generics

The following code fails to compile:

```
class MyClass<T> :  where T : MyClass <T>{}
```

Is there any way to solve this?
I have used the following workaround but I was wondering if there is a better way

```
class MyClass <T> : IMyClass where T : IMyClass {}
interface IMyClass {}
```

Comment: It would help if you accepted answers to some of your previous questions...

Comment: Can you explain what use you believe this curious pattern has? This smells like an abuse of generics. There might be a better way to do what you want.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: It's the standard way to refer to the 'current' class... like `this` for the current object. I believe it's actually quite common. Why do you think it smells?

Comment: @dtb: If that's the intention then it doesn't actually work. Consider class C<T> where T:C<T>{} class D:C<D>{} class E:C<D>{} Now your 'this-type' inside E is D, but E and D have no relationship to each other. I consider it a smell because I want generics to be used to *parameterize types* for the purposes of *reusing implementation details* like you do with a "list of something". Using generics for "tricky" purposes that as we've seen, provide no guarantees of working as you'd like them to, seems dangerous and confusing.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: But it allows to express Haskell's `class Addable a where add :: a -> a -> a` in C#: `interface IAddable<T> where T : IAddable<T> { T Add(T other); } class MyInt : IAddable<MyInt> { public MyInt Add(MyInt other) { return new MyInt(this.value + other.value); } }` Sure, MyInt could implement IAddable<MyDouble> but that wouldn't hurt if it knows how to add a MyDouble to itself and return the result as MyDouble, right? I think it's quite elegant.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Admit you love it: `T Sum<T>(IEnumerable<T> s) where T : IAddable<T> { return s.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Add(y)); }` :-)

Comment: @dtb: That is pretty slick and I have no problem with that sort of thing. When you present an actual *sensible application* of a pattern that's one thing; the original question here gives no hint as to why this curious pattern is desired. I still maintain that there might be a better way. (I also note that it usually makes more sense to do this sort of thing on interfaces than on classes.)

Comment: @thecoop: you are assuming there were accepted answers. There haven't been.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put a colon after the class name only if you want to derive the class from a base class or implement an interface:

```
class MyClass<T> where T : MyClass<T>
//              ↑
//              no ':' here
```